# how to sync time between android server and c client?

Tags: android, c, android-fragments, android-activity

I have developed an android server and c client.Data transfer is possible. But if I want to sync time in client with reference to android server. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

[NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) is the thing you are looking for, there are various [NTP client](https://github.com/sufficiently-secure/ntp-sync) available in Android. You can try that.

Or you can simply ping some time servers on regular interval and manage the internal time clock on your side.